# Don't work debugging in Visual Studio 2012+Qt Visual Studio add-in 1.2.1

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

When i run(F5) following code in Visual Studio 2012 with installed QT Visual Studio add-in 1.2.1

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel lbl("Hello");
    lbl.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

everything works fine, but when I try to debug this code(F10) it outputs error, that there is missed source file `qtmain_win.cpp`. However I don't have this file in project or overall on PC. How can I rid off from this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting the debug with *F10*, put some break-points (where you need them), start with *F5* and after the debugger stops at break-points you can step-over with *F10* and this way you debug your code and not Qt's code.

If you really want to debug Qt, you need to install the source code too (when you install the Qt version you need) and then you can point to the files from Qt's source code and step trough those too.

Comment: Thanks, it's helped me. But is it normal that, when I use cdb in QtCreator and press f10 in project it behaves like I run application, and I have to create breakpoint in order to force it works properly.